Tightness regarding bounded linear operators in the dual of $C_b$.
Let me fix the context first. We take for a locally compact polish space $X;\ \mathcal M(X)$ to be the space of finite signed Radon measures. Now suppose $(\mu_n)_{n\ge1}\subset \mathcal M(X) $ be a sequence. Since $\mathcal M(X)$ acts on $C_b(X)$ via integration we identify these elements in $C_b(X)^*$ as $T_\mu$ corresponding to $\mu\in \mathcal M(X)$.
We define property (P) : $\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists K_\epsilon\subset_{\text{compact}}X \text{ such that}\ |L(f)|\le \epsilon\|f\|$ for all $f\in C_b(X)$ with $f|_{K_\epsilon}=0$ for an element $L\in C_b(X)^*$.
We say the sequence $(\mu_n)$ is uniformly tight if; given $\epsilon>0\ \exists K_\epsilon\subset_{\text{compact}}X \text{ such that}\sup_{n\ge1}|\mu_n|(X\backslash K_\epsilon)<\epsilon.$ We know that if the sequence $(\mu_n)$ is uniformly tight then $(T_{\mu_n})$ satisfies property (P) uniformly over $n$.
What I want to know if the converse is true?
Update : Atleast when $X=\mathbb R^N$ the converse seems to hold. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.
Suppose $T_n\colon= T_{\mu_n}$ satisfies (P) uniformly over $n$. Now for $\epsilon>0\ \exists K_\epsilon$ such that $\sup_n|T_n(f)|\le\epsilon$ for all $f\in C_b(X);\ f|_{K_\epsilon}=0,\ \|f\|\le 1$. We also have the representation(Evans-Gariepy pp-64) $\forall f\in C_b;\ T_n(f)=\int_Xf\sigma_n\ d|\mu_n|$ where $|\sigma_n|=1\ ,|\mu_n|$- a.e in $X$. Denote $P_n^{\pm}=\{\sigma_n=\pm1\}\cap X\backslash K_\epsilon$ and taking $f=(1_{P^+_n}-1_{P^-_n})*\eta_m $ one can see by DCT that $|\mu_n|(X\backslash K_\epsilon)\le\epsilon$ and this holds for every $n$ so the tightness follows.
